# CSS in Safari 6, FF 19 vs. IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

I created pagination that looks good in FF 19 and Safari 6, but terrible in IE 8 (see my screenshots). How to get IE 8 to show it like FF?

FF 19:

[image: FF 19]

IE 8:

[image: IE 8]

Heres my HTML for it:

```
<div class="tc_page_top">
    <a title="erste Seite" href="#1"><img src="images/resultset_first_small.png"/></a>
    <a title="vorige Seite" href="#0"><img src="images/resultset_previous_small.png"/></a>
    &emsp;Seite 1 von 7&emsp;
    <a title="nächste Seite" href="#2"><img src="images/resultset_next_small.png"/></a>
    <a title="letzte Seite" href="#7"><img src="images/resultset_last_small.png"/></a>
    &emsp;
    <a  class="on" href="#1">1</a>
    <a href="#2">2</a>
    <a href="#3">3</a>
    <a href="#4">4</a>
    <a href="#5">5</a>
    <a href="#6">6</a>
    <a href="#7">7</a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#tc_frame {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #666666;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px #222222;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",sans-serif;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    width: 760px;
}
.tc_page_top, .tc_page_bottom {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #006;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.tc_page_top a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: thin solid #999;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.tc_page_top a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    border-style: inset;
}
.tc_page_top a.on {
    color: #003;
    background-color: #9CF;
    border-color: #009;
}
.tc_page_top a img {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Now, by adding `border="0"` to the `img`-tag, I got rid of those borders. Still, ...

- the buttons are not vertically aligned on bottom
- `border-radius`is completely ignored by IE 8

[image][image][image][image]

How can I go about fixing this in IE 8?

Comment: No CSS-driven rounded corners as far as I know

Comment: @PerfectDark: I guess jsfiddle, right? how to include the images?

Comment: @PerfectDark: images are in the question at the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/SKbEC/

Answer (score 0):

.Internet explorer doesn't support css rounded corners like border-radius.and also use vertical-align: bottom.
use overflow: hidden to the parent element of all a tags, then use float:left on all a tags

Comment: a pity. experimenting with pie at the moment. `bottom` is messing up the alignment in FF though...

Comment: What will overflow: hidden do? float:left is - surprise - bringeing all the <a>s left, I don't want them there, though.